# REST convention and backend endpoints URI mappings and methods placement

Tags: rest, uri, naming-conventions, endpoint

I've got an issue with REST naming convention and backend endpoints placement. Let's assume that we have a system which has domain objects like: Product and Survey. Each product has some survey attached to it. Survey is a form which has questions which users fill when they rate the product. I would like to have operation like 'get survey for product with concrete id'. Possible endpoints in my opinion are:

1. /survey/product/{idProduct}
2. /product/{idProduct}/survey

More logical and natural is the second option. But now problem is with Controllers. We have ProductController and SurveyController. ProductController is mapped by root URI /product and SurveyController is mapped with /survey URI. So each method which starts with /product should be placed in ProductController, same with /survey.
If we choose second option then we should put concrete method which gets survey for product in the ProductController. But it can be confusing that ProductController serves Survey. It should rather operate on Product. More natural way for developer is that SurveyController returns Survey. It does not matter that ProductController uses SurveyService e.g. to get survey for concrete product. We can always use mapping in SurveyController where we put method which returns survey for concrete product and is mapped by URI /product/{id}/survey but this can be also confusing and time consuming for developer to find method declaration and we cannot annotate controller with some root URI path.

What is better? To use strict convention that URI which starts with e.g. /product is always assigned with ProductController and developer can quickly find method by URI, but method can serve different domain objects, not only Product or to use different URIs with some root path across different controllers?

Problem can look simple if we have few controllers and few domain objects. But what when we consider system with about 100 domain objects?

Answer (score 0):

With 100 domain objects, one has usually some kind of structure for orientation. That means a dependency graph which somewhat dictates how to split the domain, even into separate projects, or separate runnable applications (microservices). So incidentally a larger model actually is "easier".

I would probably think about which resource is at the core of my model. For example if a `Product` may exists without a survey, but a `Survey` does not make sense without a `Product`, I would perhaps make the `media-type` of `Survey` link to a `Product`, rather than the other way. Which would probably look like:

```
/survey/123  <-- contains link to /product/456
```

In practice this means that you don't have to actually provide "subresources" like what you proposed.

Comment: My case rather assumes that Survey can exist without any products. It can be created, modified, etc. and maintained separately so some kind of Survey controller (even for CRUD) is needed. Microservices are good approach but not always the best solution. Let assume that we do not want to build separate system to maintain Survey and we have Survey controller responsible for serving Surveys.

Comment: Ok, the point is that one (or even both) link to the other. If they link, there is really no need to explicitly have a subresource if I understand your use-case properly.

Comment: To be honest I do not understand.I would have separate subresources to properly maintain different 'things' and actions like 1. get survey with id - /survey/id, 2. get product with some id - /product/id, 3. get survey for product with id - /product/id/survey . Then I would like to have separate controllers for Product and Survey. Where to put the 3rd action, rather in Product controller or Survey controller? I could also ask for Product object with /product/id and then by survey id contained in Product object ask for concrete Survey by /survey/id but it is redundant in my opinion

Comment: I suspect you want to hardcode the URI "template" in the client maybe? For example to get survey for product "123", client does `GET /product/123/survey` or something like that. If you are doing REST however, you should be actually following links, not "jumping" in with a hardcoded URI. In which case you would link instead of presenting easy-to-hardcode URIs.

Comment: Ok, I think I got you now. That is true I would hardcode URIs on the client side. Providing links to resources where you can "jump" is better approach then hardcoding them. It is HATEOS I guess? But my question is linked with both approaches. Even if I get the URI by link to follow or have it hardcoded I am not sure where should I place backend method to serve the data. If I go to `GET /product/123/survey` where (in which controller) should I place the method on the server-side to handle this request? If URI starts with /product it is not obvious to put the mapping in the Survey controller

Comment: Exactly, it is HATEOAS. If you use it you only need `/product/456` and `/survey/123`, both can link to each other in the content body. There is no need to expose another resource, and your controllers can also stay "clean".